# Why SharePoint Workflow starts after 5 minutes?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

Users have two ways of inserting document in a library:
  1. Silverlight screen that uses httphandler to insert document
  2. WCF that is hosted in windows service (this is called from external app)

When I use option 1, workflow starts immediately. The problem is, when I add a document using option 2, the workflow starts exactly 5 minutes after document is added.

I have checked the Workflow Timer Job and made sure runs every 1 minute. I have made sure that all settings such as: throttle, batch and etc are set for best performance.

Any ideas what delays the workflow starts?
Thanks

Comment: by default the "Workflow" timer job was set to run every 5 minutes and the "Workflow Failover" timer job every 15 minutes...could you please make sure...also when you insert using the wcf...check the ULS logs and see if you can trace some thing....2nd thing after inserting the WCF,try to run the workflow timer job manually and see if workflow executed.

Comment: I set both, "Worfklow" and "Workflow Failover" to run every minute and nothing changes. Even when i manually restart workflow timer job the workflows are not been executed. It is always that delay of 5 minutes